# Using a value of a map stored in a module attribute in function pattern matching

Tags: elixir

Given that module attributes are resolved at compilation, I thought the following two line pairs would be equivalent but the second generates a `cannot invoke remote function` error.  What I'm trying to do is use a module attribute containing a map as an `enum`. Then I want to pattern match in the function against one of the `enum`'s values.

```
@my_guard "bar" 

def foo(@my_guard), do: "bar"


@my_map %{guard: "bar"}

def foo(@my_map.guard), do: "bar"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function the following way and it will work:

```
def foo(unquote(@my_map.guard)), do: "bar"
```

The problem is that your example turns into this at the compile time:

```
def foo(%{guard: "bar"}.guard), do: "bar"
```

which is not a proper pattern matching.

Comment: Just one unquote is enough: `def foo(unquote(@my_map.guard)), do: "bar"`.

Comment: @Dogbert Yeah you are right, didn't really think about it, thanks

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  It just seems like, in this case, the compiler could transform it all the way to `def foo("bar"), do: "bar"`.  Especially since I can create a new attribute right before the function using `@my_new_guard @my_map.guard` and then use `def foo(@my_new_guard), do: "bar"` and that works.